# Go Transport connection keepalive when DNS changes

Tags: go, networking, tcp, dns

I'm currently writing a proxy using go. I'm using the [ReverseProxy](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy) from the standard library and also the default [Transport](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport) from the standard library.

Suppose for this question that we only have one origin host for the proxy. We set `DisableKeepAlives` to be false, allow more than one idle connection to the origin server and set the `IdleConnTimeout` to be 60 seconds.

Suppose a client uses the proxy to make one request to the origin host every 10 seconds. The first connection will cause a DNS lookup to find the IP of the origin host. The transport will keep a connection open to that IP which will never be closed as we keep re-using it before the timeout. The way that go caches the connection is on the host rather than the IP.

Now suppose that the DNS record for that host changes and points to a new IP. We will still have our connection open to the original IP, and because this never gets closed, we never need to make a new connection and so will not start communicating to the new IP (on the assumption that the original host is still active after the dns change).

What pattern is appropriate if we want to design the system in such a way that it is responsive to DNS changes? One idea I had was to have an infinite loop which [closes any idle connections](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport.CloseIdleConnections) which exist every N seconds. This would work for the toy example above but in the case where we have much more traffic flowing through, then there's a good chance that a request will be in-flight during the flush.

An alternative to that would be to just set a maximum length of time that a connection can be alive for. However I can't see a way to manipulate the standard library to achieve this.

Can anyone advise on a design which would be responsive to a DNS change?

Comment: Closing idle connections won’t effect any that are in use, because they are not “idle”. Just set `IdleConnTimeout` to do this automatically.

Comment: I am setting `IdleConnTimeout`. The problem arises when a connection never actually lies idle for that long. I would still like the connection to eventually be closed regardless so when a new connection is created it uses the updated dns.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying, it's not the idle connections you're really concerned with. Now that the Transport has `IdleConnTimeout`, The brute force method of swapping out the transport is probably the easiest to coordinate.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the question, it seems that the proxy implementation was designed to use an ip as an endpoint.

If you cannot avoid using hostnames as your target endpoints, you could configure your [`httputil.ReverseProxy.Director`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy) to resolve the hostnames. At the expense of the lookup time (could be configured to only lookup when the dns ttl expires), you'd get realtime updated target endpoints, while still utilizing the [`http.Transport`s](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Transport) connection cache.

Example `Director`:

```
func director(req *http.Request) {
    addrs, err := net.LookupHost("yourdomain.com")
    if err != nil {
        handle(err)
    }
    if len(addrs) < 1 {
        handle(fmt.Errorf("No addresses found"))
    }

    req.URL.Host = addrs[0]
}
```

Comment: I think this should get me most of the way there thanks! A remaining issue is that if I'm only passing IP addresses to the Transport, then I cannot securely connect to origin servers using TLS (as these require the hostname). I think I could get around this by keeping a map of IPs to hostnames and doing a lookup when I connect. Is there a cleaner way?

Comment: You can set `req.Host`, which will set the `Host` header, to be the domain name in question. In the director function: `req.URL.Scheme = "https"` `req.URL.Host = addrs[0]` and `req.Host = "thing.com"` This works quite well for me.

Comment: But in the `Transport`, when we dial and make the connection we only use the address of the origin server to connect to (`DialTLS func(network, addr string) (net.Conn, error)`). In our case the address is the IP so we can't configure tls with the expected servername?